# Split CSV file into small number of csv files based on value of a column

Tags: powershell

I am trying to split a csv file into smaller csv files, on the basis of the `BusinessUnit` which is a column in the csv file.

Until now I've tried:-

```
$fullpath = "C:\Batch\Output Folder\ErroreportforAllregions.csv"

$path = Split-Path $fullpath -parent
$data = Import-CSV  -Path $fullpath -Header BusinessUnit,Date,Time,PolicyNum


foreach ($group in $data | Group BusinessUnit){        
    $data | Where-Object {$_.species -eq $group.name} | 
        ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
         foreach {$_.Replace('"','')}|
        Out-File "$path\$($group.name).csv"     
}
```

But in this rows(data) are not coming in small csv files. Please guide me as to where I am making the mistake.

My data in big csv file:-

```
BusinessUnit    serialno
Eastern Region   1
Ottawa           2
India            3
```

The output should be

- EasternRegion.csv
- Ottawa.csv
- India.csv

Comment: The example you give for the big csv does not look like it has headers `BusinessUnit,Date,Time,PolicyNum` at all??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your big csv actually looks like this:

```
"BusinessUnit","Date","Time","PolicyNum","serialno"
"Eastern Region","2019-02-04","11:09:45","123","1"
"Eastern Region","2019-02-03","10:09:45","123","1"
"Ottawa","2019-02-04","11:09:45","123","1"
"India","2019-02-04","11:09:45","123","1"
```

Then this should do it:

```
$fullpath = "C:\Batch\Output Folder\ErroreportforAllregions.csv"
$path = Split-Path $fullpath -parent
$data = Import-CSV -Path $fullpath

$data | Group-Object -Property BusinessUnit | ForEach-Object {
    $file = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($_.Name + '.csv')
    $_.Group | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Using the data from above, it will create three csv files called `Eastern Region.csv`, `Ottawa.csv` and `India.csv`.

**Eastern Region.csv**

```
"BusinessUnit","Date","Time","PolicyNum","serialno"
"Eastern Region","2019-02-04","11:09:45","123","1"
"Eastern Region","2019-02-03","10:09:45","123","1"
```

**Ottawa.csv**

```
"BusinessUnit","Date","Time","PolicyNum","serialno"
"Ottawa","2019-02-04","11:09:45","123","1"
```

**India.csv**

```
"BusinessUnit","Date","Time","PolicyNum","serialno"
"India","2019-02-04","11:09:45","123","1"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Theo..Yes you got the question correctly and this is working perfectly.Thank you so much

Comment: out of few answers on the site, this one worked Thanks